# How do I manipulate the parse data accordingly?

Tags: ios, swift, parse-platform

So basically I am trying to fetch data from parse and show the data accordingly.

How do I view the information and also add information to the tableview of my items.

I have a reservedList class in parse which gives out the userid and username of the person who confirmed a list.

I am not sure how to display the items on the view controller. Everytime i try to print the usernames to the label i get a blank label. and i would like to know how to implement the `UITableView` to show my data –

gettting error

> "**Could not cast value of type '__NSArrayM' (0x103cbb8d8) to
>   'NSString' (0x10412fb20).**" when i print out the items.

I have a reservedCust class in parse which contains the [following](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Ohb1c.png)

[this it the format I would like to view the data in](https://i.stack.imgur.com/n0yAk.png)

```
var usernames = [String]()
var userids = [String]()
var times = [String]()
var items = [String]()

@IBOutlet var reserveTime: UILabel!
@IBOutlet var reserveUser: UILabel!
@IBOutlet var reservedItems: UITableView!


override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()

    let reserveList = PFQuery(className: "reservedList")
    reserveList.findObjectsInBackgroundWithBlock { (objects, error) -> Void in


        if let objects = objects {

            self.usernames.removeAll(keepCapacity: true)
            self.times.removeAll(keepCapacity: true)
            for object in objects {

                if let username = object["username"] as? String {

                    self.usernames.append((object["username"] as? String)!)

                }

                var reservedUser = object["userid"] as? String

                var query = PFQuery(className: "reservedCust")

                query.whereKey("userid", equalTo: reservedUser!)

                query.findObjectsInBackgroundWithBlock({ (objects, error) -> Void in

                    if let objects = objects {

                        for object in objects {



                            if let time = object["time"] as? String {

                                self.times.append((object["time"] as? String)!)
                            }
                             if let item = object["items"] {
                                self.items.append(object["items"] as! (String))
                            }






                        }
                        print(self.usernames)
                        print(self.times)
                        print(self.items)
                    }




                })
            }
        }



    }


    // Do any additional setup after loading the view.




}
```

Comment: you need to explain what your code does wrong

Comment: im not sure how to display the items on the view controller.  everytime i try to print  the usernames to the label i get a blank label.
 and i would like to know how to implement the uitableview to show my data

Comment: You are not parsing data correctly. You are trying to cast NSArray into NSString.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First declare two class variables.

```
var countOfObjects : Int! // Holds count for query objects from Parse

var allObjects : NSArray! // All queried objects from Parse
```

Than in your `viewDidLoad()`

```
override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()

    getDataFromParse() // A helper method to fetch data from Parse
    // Initialize for countOfObjects to 0 on viewDidLoad
    countOfObjects = 0
}

func getDataFromParse() {
    let query = PFQuery(className:"YourClassName") 

    query.findObjectsInBackgroundWithBlock { (object : [PFObject]?, error : NSError?) -> Void in

        print(object!.count)

        //set  count Of Objects
        self.countOfObjects = object?.count

        // Set allObjects
        self.allObjects = object

        //Reload TableView after query
        self.YouRTableView.reloadData()
    }

}

// MARK: - TableView DataSource

func tableView(tableView: UITableView, numberOfRowsInSection section: Int) -> Int{

    return countOfObjects
}

func tableView(tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAtIndexPath indexPath: NSIndexPath) -> UITableViewCell {

    let cell = tableView.dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier(YourCellIdentifier, forIndexPath: indexPath) as! YourTableViewCell

    if let object = allObjects {
        let currentObject = object.objectAtIndex(indexPath.row)
        cell.textLabel?.text = currentObject.valueForKey("somekey") // Assign label text from parse.
      }

    return cell

}
```

Comment: ` cell.YourLabel.text = currentObject.valueForKey("YourKey") as! NSString // Assign label text from parse`

i get issue uiview has no member text

Comment: You need to create IBOutlet of label in your tableViewCell class.

Comment: i have already done that. I've created uitableviewcell cocoa class. and in that iboutlet called label.

Comment: You mean Cocoa touch (not cocoa). And you have assigned custom class to cell. And also you are using YourTableViewCell in dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier method?

Comment: yea cocoa touch class for ios. 
`func tableView(tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAtIndexPath indexPath: NSIndexPath) -> UITableViewCell {
        
        let mycell = tableView.dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier("items", forIndexPath: indexPath) as! randomTableViewCell
        
        if let object = allObjects {
            let currentObject = object.objectAtIndex(indexPath.row)
            mycell.label!.text = (currentObject.valueForKey("items") as! NSString)  // Assign label text from parse.
        }
        
        return mycell
        
    }
`

returns error as mentioned above

Comment: I have edited my answer. Remove as! NSString and see if it works.

Comment: actually i tried `mycell.label!.text = "test"` this and its still returns uiview has no member text. the .text function is not being detected for reason. tried your edit too. still :(

Comment: From your error I am guessing you have not created IBOutlet of label but have created IBOutlet of a UIView. Can you update your question and include yourTableViewCell code?

Comment: wow. you're right. now it asks me to delete valueForKey or 20
fatal error: unexpectedly found nil while unwrapping an Optional value